# sudden increase in arp entries when i rlogin from one node to another node

Tags: networking, arp

when I r-login from my one host to another, I am observing sudden increase in arp entries from 80 to 900. and this is causing neighbour table overflow. can anyone suggest why this is happening??

before r-login:

```
ip -4 neigh show nud all | wc -l
81
```

after r-login:

```
ip -4 neigh show nud all | wc -l
890
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a conclusive answer, but as is mentioned in this post

[ARP broadcast flooding network and high cpu usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/555066/arp-broadcast-flooding-network-and-high-cpu-usage)

You could use something like mac-address-table notification to see which party is the offending one.

Also consider the possibility that perhaps not only r-login is causing this, you could test with Telnet to see if the issue occurs with that as well.

Comment: i tried ssh and telnet. it didnt cause increase in arp entries.
its occuring only when i use rlogin.

Comment: interesting that its only rlogin

If you temporarily remove any /etc/hosts.equiv and .rhosts on the remote side, restart xinetd and retry does this reoccur?

Comment: well this didn't work too @sam perry

Comment: No solution for this??

Comment: No alternatives ?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot think of much else; does connecting via rlogin to a different machine cause the same issue or is it just this one?